# Source Data Partitioning is disabled in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to import an external table that has hive partitioned information on it in GCS. 
The structure of file has the following format.

```
gs://bucket/events/year=2020/month=03/day=23/hour=0/
gs://bucket/events/year=2020/month=03/day=23/hour=1/
```

The files under these folders are in JSON format.

When I try to create the table in BigQuery, the UI editor doesn't allow me to enter Source URI information. The option comes up as follows.

[image]

Does anyone know what could be the issue around this? Why is the source URI information coming up disabled? Is it something to do with permissions or the way partitions are created in the structure above?

Comment: Saw you created a bug, meanwhile, command line should work: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs#setting_hivepartitioningoptions_using_the_command-line_tool

Comment: Thanks Yun Zhang. I've tried that as well. Posted another question around that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838904/creating-external-table-from-gcs-with-hive-partition-information-in-bigquery-usi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine in your partition format. Besides that, the problem is not related to permissions (even if you have some permission problem). I tried to reproduce your issue and found the same problem. As it was working fine some days ago, the problem is on `Big Query`'s new release and not on your side.

When the box `Source data partitioning` is marked you should see:

[image]

If you think this problem affects you and other persons I encourage you to create a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659) reporting this problem.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I've opened an issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152293190

Comment: I hope they fix it quickly :) If this answer helped you addressing you problem somehow, consider accepting or upvoting