# Creating External table from GCS with hive partition information in BigQuery using Command Line

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bucket in google cloud storage with the following naming hierarchy.

```
gs://<bucket>/events/year=2020/month=03/day=23/hour=12
```

I've used the following command to create a BigQuery Native table with hive partitioned information to import from google cloud store. This works.

```
bq load --project_id=<projectId> --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect --hive_partitioning_mode=AUTO --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix=gs://<bucket>/events/ <targetTableName> "gs://<bucket>/events/*" "<schema>"
```

And the following query works as well.

```
SELECT * from table WHERE year=2020
```

But, when I try to do the same with an external table, the table is created with the hive partition information. But the queries do not recognise any of the partitions.

```
bq mkdef --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect --hive_partitioning_mode=AUTO --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix="gs://<bucket>/events" --require_hive_partition_filter=True "gs://<bucket>/events/*" > <table_Def>

bq mk --dataset_id=<datasetId> --data_source=google_cloud_storage --external_table_definition=<tableDef> --schema=<schema> --table <tableName>
```

And the following query does not work.

```
SELECT * from table WHERE year=2020
```

The documentation states, that this should be supported. Would someone please be able to tell what I am missing here?

Comment: When you say 'query does not work,' what are the results you obtain? and what are the ones that do work? Let's compare them. Also, can you share the schema definition file and verify that BigQuery created the table correctly?

Comment: When I say that the query does not work, I mean BigQuery does not consider `year` to be a column. It says unknown column and doesn't even run. The queries that does work is `SELECT * from table`. I've checked that BigQuery did create the table correctly, because I can see all the columns provided in the schema definition being recognised. I can even print them back as part of `bq list` command. Apologies, I won't be able to share the schema definition as its IPR. But the schema should not be the issue here as it work when I create a Native table.

Comment: I get the table created with bq mk, but it is failing on querying with error: " Failed to add partition key year". It is a bit difficult to follow your steps without a schema. However, it works for my case if I load from [the BigQuery UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs#setting_hivepartitioningoptions_using_the_web_ui) as an external table and select  Auto Detect Schema.